# iTunes alternative for managing iPhone 3G

Tags: linux, iphone, itunes, software-rec

I'm totally sick and tired to starting my VMWare and run the Windows VM, and opening iTunes every time I want to do something with my iPhone.

Is there any alternatives out there for iPhone 3G on 3.0 firmware?

I don't mind jailbreaking it.

Comment: It would depend on what you mean by "managing". What do you want to do? Get music on it? Edit your contact lists ?

Comment: I guess we should assume your OS is unix/linux?

Comment: From this point of view - iPhone is a no-go, NEVER!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to jailbreak your iphone.  You did not mention what flavor of linux you were using.  Here is some info related to Ubuntu.

---

http://fatbuttlarry.blogspot.com/2010/01/ipod-touch-iphone-3g-ubuntu-910-in-5.html

Comment: NOTE: Ubuntu 10.04 already supports the file transfer. Don't know if you need a break. Try it without that first.